# Collection select returning null value in first position

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, multi-select

I'm just trying to get a list box working that allows multiple values to be selected. It is correctly passing a set of user id's but the first parameter passed is null. I don't have any null values in the source table so I'm puzzled where this is coming from. I'm probably doing something basic wrong so any help much appreciated.

from log file:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0Ia2kGYj1qidP6saEOfAjywDQkbds+cbFBzJ1H3UyRE=", "user_ids"=>["", "3", "4"], "commit"=>"Add Users to Group", "id"=>"create_multiple"}
  `[1m[35mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`user_id` IN (0, 3, 4)`
```

Code from view:

```
<%= form_for :user, :url => create_multiple_user_roles_path, :html => { :method => :put } do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= collection_select(:user, :user_ids, @users, :id, :last_name,
      { :selected => :user_ids },
    {:multiple => true, :name => 'user_ids[]', :size => 10, :include_blank => false }  ) %>
  </p>
  <%= submit_tag "Add Users to Group" %>
```

Comment: Paul, by chance have you found an answer for this?  I am having the same problem with the null entry in the first position.  I am going to ask the question again :)

Answer (score 1):

put the  :include_blank in the first hash like  as follows

```
 <%= collection_select(:user, :user_ids, @users, :id, :last_name,
  { :selected => :user_ids,:include_blank => false },
{:multiple => true, :name => 'user_ids[]', :size => 10}  ) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added **:included_blank => false**, if it is false then I think you don't need it. Please remove it and check again. I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: I still have the same issue even when selecting a single option. "user_ids"=>["", "3"]

Comment: Unfortunately that hasn't worked either - thanks for your continued help.